# Error: Uncaught (in promise): SecurityError: The operation is insecure

Tags: javascript, angular

I am working on `Angular 4` project and I am converting Image to `base64` string. When I assign this string to `img` tag, it is giving below error :
`Error: Uncaught (in promise): SecurityError: The operation is insecure.`

**My code :**

```
var reader: FileReader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
reader.onloadend = reader.result;
```

How do I solve this ?

Comment: It looks a Firefox error. It looks like an error it may happen when you have CORS and the canvas you use isn't happy about creating the `base64`. To be sure: are you sure that the error comes from the new image URL assignment? Is the original image from another domain?

Comment: @MarcoL I am converting image to base64 and then assigning that base64 to image `src`.

Comment: How do you convert it to base64?

Comment: @MarcoL using `FileReader`.

Comment: Can you post your code in a JSFiddle?

Comment: @MarcoL Check updated post.

Comment: Have a look to MDN to see how the FileReader API works: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL

Comment: Do you want to convert image url into dataURLor file to dataURL ?